# How to exclude a git branch from being built in travis?

Tags: github, travis-ci

I have a github project that I'm building with travis.  https://travis-ci.org/emmby/greenDAO/branches

I want travis to build most of the branches in that project, but there's one in particular that I wish to exclude.

So I added the following to `.travis.yml` on my `master` branch:

```
branches:
  except:
    - mvn-repo
```

However, that didn't disable building of the branch.  So reading up on [the docs](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/build-configuration/#Specify-branches-to-build), I came across this note:

> Please note that currently (for historical reasons), .travis.yml needs
>   to be present on all active branches of your project.

So, I went ahead and created a `.travis.yml` file in the `mvn-repo` branch which contains the same `branches` section.  However, travis still insists on building and failing my `mvn-repo` branch.

Why is travis trying to build a branch that I've marked for exclusion?

Comment: What does Travis call an "active branch"? Are the contents of this file the same on all said active branches? It looks like you only updated the contents on the branch you wish to be excluded, from what you say.

Comment: I had the same question.  Hopefully they don't mean literally ALL, since one or two of the branches are pull requests and I don't want to pollute them with unrelated changes like a .travis.yml file.

Comment: The docs are very clear: "Travis will always look for the `.travis.yml` file that is contained in the branch specified by the git commit that GitHub has passed to us." So _active_ means, all branches that you commit to on GitHub.

Comment: So wouldn't that mean that the .travis.yml in the mvn-repo branch should have prevented the mvn-repo branch from being built?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see a .travis.yml in your mvn-repo branch (https://github.com/emmby/greenDAO/tree/mvn-repo)

Comment: Ah, my build system appears to have deleted it.  I'll bet that's the problem then.

Answer (score 3):

Are you still having this issue? As you describe it, it sounds like a bug, so please report this in [our issue tracker](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/new), and we'll take a look for you.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Currently, travis-ci has a switch that decides whether or not to build a branches that do not contain a .travis.yml file.